# Add some np arrays as new columns to my data

Tags: python, numpy

I want to add some (N x 1) np.arrays, as new columns to another np.array (N x M)

I have tried many things (append, transposing, hstack etc) but for some reason I cannot make it work.

For example:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
b=[100,200,300,400]
c=[100,200,300,400]
d=[100,200,300,400]
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
1,2,3,100,100,100
4,5,6,200,200,200
7,8,9,300,300,300
10,11,12,400,400,400
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.c_` to combine the data by columns:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
b = [100,200,300,400]
c = [100,200,300,400]
d = [100,200,300,400]

np.c_[a, b, c, d]
```

```
array([[  1,   2,   3, 100, 100, 100],
       [  4,   5,   6, 200, 200, 200],
       [  7,   8,   9, 300, 300, 300],
       [ 10,  11,  12, 400, 400, 400]])
```

You can also use ``column_stack'' to get the same result:

```
np.column_stack([a, b, c, d])
```

```
array([[  1,   2,   3, 100, 100, 100],
       [  4,   5,   6, 200, 200, 200],
       [  7,   8,   9, 300, 300, 300],
       [ 10,  11,  12, 400, 400, 400]])
```

Thanks to [josemz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8998310/josemz) for the more concise version.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I get this error:
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Did you get this error using the data above? If not, what data were you using instead? You may want to try using ``np.column_stack``.

Comment: @Nathaniel with column stack you can do it in one go

Comment: @josemz Good point! I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate them on the last axis:

```
In [329]: a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]) 
     ...: b=np.array([[100,200,300,400]]).T         # transpose a (1,4)
     ...: c=np.array([100,200,300,400])[:,None]     # add a dimension
     ...: d=np.array([[100],[200],[300],[400]])     # list of lists 

In [330]: np.concatenate([a,b,c,d], axis=-1)                                    
Out[330]: 
array([[  1,   2,   3, 100, 100, 100],
       [  4,   5,   6, 200, 200, 200],
       [  7,   8,   9, 300, 300, 300],
       [ 10,  11,  12, 400, 400, 400]])
```

Checking the shapes:

```
In [331]: [i.shape for i in [a,b,c,d]]                                          
Out[331]: [(4, 3), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1)]
```

But the `b` that you show, `np.array([100,200,300,400])` is (4,) shaped, not (4,1).  So it requires an array reshape, such as that provided by `column_stack`.